# Can't find out what's wrong with my code? (2D Matrix convolution with numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, convolution

I just learned about matrix convolution from Andrew Ng's deeplearning.ai coursera course and I wanted to try to make my own 2D matrix convolution using numpy but I keep getting the following error. (bottom of the code)

I don't understand what I did wrong as f = 100 and w = 0 for the first iteration so I don't get why `aSlice = dataColor[vertStart:vertEnd, vertStart:vertEnd]` is a 100 by 99 matrix. I tried to do a +1 to "horiEnd" but it becomes 100 by 101 instead. I also tried `assert(dataColor.shape == (1200,1200))` but that doesn't seem to be the problem either. I think the problem starts after the for loops. Any help would be greatly apprieciated.

````
def convSingleStep(aSlice, F = np.full((100,100), 0.000001)):
    #F = f*f filter
    s = aSlice*F
    Z = np.sum(s)
    
    return Z



def convForward(dataColor, F = np.full((100,100), 0.000001)):
    nH, nW = dataColor.shape         #1200 x 1200
    f, f = F.shape                   #100 x 100
    theNewSlice = np.zeros((nH, nW)) #1200 x 1200
    
    for h in range(nH): #nH = 1200
        vertStart = h
        vertEnd = h + f
        
        for w in range(nW): #nW = 1200
            horiStart = w
            horiEnd = w + f
            aSlice = dataColor[vertStart:vertEnd, horiStart:horiEnd]
            theNewSlice[h, w] = convSingleStep(aSlice, F = np.full((100,100), 0.000001))
            
    return theNewSlice
```----> 3     s = aSlice*F
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (100,99) (100,100)```
````

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: @wwii yes I get that python can't broadcast dataColor.shape = (100,99) and F.shape = (100,100) together but I don't get why dataColor.shape[1] is 99 and dataColor.shape[0] is 100 since they are both derived the same way

Comment: When you get to the end of the inner loop `horiStart` is `1101` and `horiEnd` is `1201` but since there are only 1200 items in that dimension you start getting *slices* that are less than 100.  If you are using an IDE, **now** is the time to learn its debugging features. Printing stuff in the loop can be effective also.

Comment: i.e. `datacolor[0:100,1101:1201].shape --> (100,99)` ... Add `print(f'dataColor[{vertStart}:{vertEnd}, {horiStart}:{horiEnd}]')` just after the `aSlice=...` line. and maybe use a smaller `dataColor` like `np.ones(110,110)`.

Comment: You have to figure out a strategy for dealing with the **edges** for you convolution.

Answer (score 0):

In the first step of your loop,

```
h = 0, , vertEnd = 100
w = 0, , horiEnd = 100
aSlice.shape = (100,100)
```

This is all good and acting as expected.
But getting to the ~1,100th step (11,101)

```
h = 1100, , vertEnd = 1200 # Note the index is 1200, which requires length of 1201
w = 0, , horiEnd = 100
```

And now you are setting the shape out of the range of your data, with `vertEnd = 1200`:

```
aSlice = dataColor[vertStart:vertEnd, horiStart:horiEnd]

aSlice.shape # 99, 100
```

Here,

```
aSlice[0] = dataColor[1101:1200] = dataColor[1101:] = dataColor[1101:1200]
```